# How to make table based on the class

Tags: html, class, css-tables

My data is like this

```html
<div class="fl1">floor 1</div>
<div class="fl2">floor 2</div>
<div class="fl2">floor 2</div>
<div class="fl2">floor 2</div>
<div class="fl3">floor 3</div>
```

Is it possible to display it like this

[image: floor image]

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you have to use colspan

```
<table >
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="width:100%">TEXT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  >TEXT</td><td  >TEXT</td><td  >TEXT</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="width:100%">TEXT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Using div and flex.

```css
.cont{
width:200px;
height:100%;
border-style: solid;
}

.f1{
border-style:solid;
 margin: 2px;
}
.fl2{
 
border-style:solid;
width:100%;
margin:2px;
}
.cont2{
  display:flex;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="f1">floor1</div>
  <div class="cont2">
   <div class="fl2">floor2</div>
    <div class="fl2">floor3</div>
     <div class="fl2">floor4</div>
   </div> 
   <div class="f1">floor5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the data is retrieved from the Sharepoint list.  It uses xslt to generate the div tags. It doesn't know how many units on each floor. It can only dump data as I described.  I am wondering if it is possible to use css style or javascript to organize cells based on the class: cells with same class are placed in the same row.

Comment: You need to use only css and javascript to do the same output ?

Comment: I I basically want to ask if it is possible to build a table structure based on the classes using html, css, javascript or anything executed in user's browser

Answer (score 0):

This way basically:

```html
<div style="width:500px;border-style:double">
      <div style="border-style:solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <div>floor 1</div>
      </div> 
      <div style="display:inline-block; padding-top:2px;padding-left:1px">
        <div style="float:left;width:100px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid">floor 2</div>
        <div style="float:left;width:100px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid; margin-left:1px">
        floor 2</div>
        <div style="float:left;width:100px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid; margin-left:1px">floor 2</div>
      </div>
      <div style="border-style:solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <div>floor 1</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
```